# Strip a string if it contains a parnethesis

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, strip

I have some scraped data that varies in format slightly, however in order to standadise it I need to remove anything within the parenthesis including the parenthesis, if they exist that is. I have attempted to useing strip in various ways but to no avail.

Some example data:

```
Text (te)
Text Text (tes)
Text-Text (te)
Text Text
Text-Text (tes)
```

And how I need to appear after standardisation:

```
Text
Text Text
Text-Text
Text Text
Text-Text
```

Can anyone offer me a solution for this? Thanks SMNALLY

Comment: Did you try this: `s[:s.index('(')]`, but it is not a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the parenthesis do not nest, and that there is at most one pair per string, try this:

```
import re
myString = re.sub(r'\(.*\)', '', myString)
```

A more specific pattern might be:

```
myString = re.sub(r'\s*\(\w+\)\s*$', '', myString)
```

The above pattern deletes the whitespace that surrounds the parenthetical expression, and only deletes from the end of the line.

Answer (score 5):

```
from re import sub
x = sub("(?s)\(.*\)", "", x)
```

This will remove everything between the parenthesis (including newlines) as well as the parenthesis themselves.